# 'Long (or vertical) multiplication of polynomials (Long rule for multiplication)'

Tags: polynom

[image]

(1). How may I multiply the two polynomials vertically?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{polynom}
\newcommand*{\Ph}{\hphantom{)}}%

\begin{document}
 Example-(01) The distribution of the following product is arranged.
 \begin{flalign*}
 (x^{3}+2x^{2}+2x+1)(x^{2}-x+1)
 \end{flalign*}
 $\begin{array}{r@{} r@{} r r}
 x^3&{}+2x^2&{}+2x+ 4 \\
 \times(x^2&{}-x+1) &\\
 \cmidrule{1-3}
 \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Either I forgot math learned at University or I am misunderstanding the question: Multiplication versus Long Division?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I apologise for inconvenience caused. What I meant was vertical multiplication. I edited my question.  I think now the question is clear. Thank you for the improvement.

Comment: how would you like it to look?

Comment: The answers to [How can I make a scheme to multiply polynomials?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219621/3954) can give you some ideas.